# TemplateDoesNotExist at / blog/index.html

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create my own project with Django version 1.9.x, but I can't make the index page at `/` to work.

This is my folder structure:

```
rxe/
    urls.py
    wsgi.py
    settings.py
blog/
    migrations/
    static/
        blog/
            css/
            js/
            img/
    templates/
        blog/
           index.html
    admin.py
    models.py
    tests.py
    urls.py
    views.py
manage.py
```

`rxe/urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'$', include('blog.urls')), 
]
```

`blog/urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name = 'index'),
]
```

`blog/views.py`:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'blog/index.html'
```

When accessing `localhost:8000/`, the error:

> **TemplateDoesNotExist at /**
>
> blog/index.html

And right below it, in **Template-loader postmortem**:

> django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.9.4-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/admin/templates/blog/index.html (Source does not exist)
>
> django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.9.4-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/auth/templates/blog/index.html (Source does not exist)

It works if I return an `HttpResponse('Hello')`, like in the tutorial, but this same tutorial does not have any view for `/` path, and I want one there.

**Edit**

`rxe/settings.py`, how it was created:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
    },
]
```

Comment: @RodXavier `settings.py` file?

Comment: @warath-coder To where? Isn't there the correct place?

Comment: @RodXavier I updated the question. Is that it? In the official tutorial, I do not record of having to modify the template.

Comment: in blog/templates/index.html, then in your code just put 'index.html' in the render statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must add the `blog` app to your project by including it in your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [...,
                  'blog']
```

Otherwise the template loader will not process the `blog` directory since it is not seen as an app.

Comment: I will encountered the same problem, it turns  out I didn't add the app in setting.py. Thanks :)